# Why is Coulomb's law still relevant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, coulombs-law, approximations

There is no scenario where we can use Coulomb's law. There is no static charge. Even if we consider the local charge density to be constant for a system of charges, the individual charges are still moving, and as we know they are not quite the same. Moving charges show different effects. Even if we think about putting a frame with the particle so that we can consider the charged particle as static that also does not help because there is no single frame for a system of charge Also we want to measure the effect in our lab frame. So, how is Coulomb's law still relevant?

Comment: *There is no scenario where we can use Coulomb's law.* It works rather well, although not exactly,  in predicting the energy levels of hydrogen. Physics often involves making appropriate approximations.

Comment: But why is that? Electron is moving inside the Hydrogen atom but still, the coulombic approximation does so well predicting the energy levels.

Comment: simple demonstration of Coulomb law  https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/46/11/1131/1043415/A-simple-experiment-to-demonstrate-Coulomb-s-law?redirectedFrom=fulltext .

Comment: Potentials, and the potential  that gives Coulomb's law, are good examples in Quantum mechanics, because the wave function solutions depend on the form of the potential as well as the boundary conditions of the system. A different potential would not predict the same spectrum.

Comment: *But why is that?* Because the electron in the ground state of hydrogen moves at less than one percent of the speed of light. The magnetic interaction energy between proton and electron is a tiny fraction of the electrostatic interaction energy.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, moving charges show different effects. But how different are they really?

You can take into account the motion of the charges by applying a Lorentz transformation to the fields. Let's look at a charged particle moving at speed $\bf{v}$ in the lab frame $k'$, while in frame $k$ it is at rest.

The electromagnetic fields measured in the lab frame will be

$\textbf{E}'_\| = \textbf{E}_\|$

$\textbf{B}'_\| = \textbf{B}_\|$

$\textbf{E}'_\perp= \gamma(\textbf{E}_\perp + \textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}_\perp)$

$\textbf{B}'_\perp= \gamma(\textbf{B}_\perp - \textbf{v}/c^2 \times \textbf{E}_\perp)$

If there is no magnetic field in the particle's frame you are left with

$\textbf{E}'_\| = \textbf{E}_\|$

$\textbf{B}'_\| = 0$

$\textbf{E}'_\perp= \gamma\textbf{E}_\perp$

$\textbf{B}'_\perp= -\gamma \textbf{v}/c^2\times \textbf{E}_\perp$

This means that as long as the velocities of the particles in the material are much smaller than the speed of light, the fields don't change much, and Coulomb's law holds quite well.

Now, how fast are charges typically moving?
As an example, let's look at free electrons in a metallic conductor. They can be modelled as a Fermi gas, for which we can compute the Fermi velocity. A table with the Fermi velocity of some metals can be found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/fermi.html). The velocity is typically around $10^6$ m/s, about 100 times less than $c\approx 3\times 10^8$ m/s. This means that we can safely use Coulomb's law when dealing with metallic conductors.

Answer (score 2):

Simple because a)it has historical significance:ok so why then do we use Newtonian gravity to calculate the paths of celestial bodies since we know its only a approximation even in the weak field limit to General Relativity?and b)its a simple model:if we tried to account for everything in the nature then for the simple motion of a object we wouldnt actually be able to solve because nature is really complicated , so we use approximate models to actually solve problems and then we say that there is a error margin of 1%.